# HTML5 CSS Horizontally Scrolling multiple dynamic number of columns

Tags: css, html, multiple-columns, horizontal-scrolling

I am having a problem getting a div to scroll horizontally.
The div has a dynamic number of columns which can go over the 100% width of the page. Currently, I have the total width set to a fixed px width (1500px) to get  horizontal scrolling. However, as the number of columns is dynamic, the div should grow to fit the new columns in, and not hide the new columns below the div.

Here is a fiddle of my page stripped down:
https://jsfiddle.net/razzledazzle/jpj2cuo7/5/
You can see the last input in the column visible is 'Last one visible'. The next column with input is 'New Kanban List not visible'.

How can I change the div#board-container width to be 100% instead of 1500px and still scroll horizontally? It's a very similar layout to Trello or MeisterTask.

```
div#main-kanban {
  top: 49px;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 52px;
}

div#content-kanban {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-x: auto;
  background: #e3e3e3;
}

div#board-container {
  width: 1500px;
  top: 49px;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

section#kanban-board {
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  margin-bottom: 49px;
}

div.kanban-individual {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  width: 320px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  transition: background 0.3s linear;
}
```

Comment: An example of the layout I'm after is:
https://www.meistertask.com/

Answer (score 3):

Thanks to @ketan and @Carol McKay who pointed me on the right path. I managed to get it working as I needed by setting the height 100% for and using display:flex on div#board-container.

Here is the [Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/razzledazzle/jpj2cuo7/15/)

The working CSS:

```
div#main-kanban {
    top: 49px;
    position: absolute; 
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom:52px;
}

div#content-kanban {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0px;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-x: auto;
    background: #e3e3e3;
}

div#board-container {
    width: 100%;
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display:flex;
    height:100%;
}

section#kanban-board {
    margin-bottom:49px;
    display: -webkit-box;      /* OLD - iOS 6-, Safari 3.1-6 */
    display: -moz-box;         /* OLD - Firefox 19- (buggy but mostly works) */
    display: -ms-flexbox;      /* TWEENER - IE 10 */
    display: -webkit-flex; 
    display:flex;
}

div.kanban-individual {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;
    width: 320px;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    float: left;    
    background-color: #e3e3e3;
    cursor: pointer;
    -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    -o-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    -ms-transition: background 0.3s linear;
    transition: background 0.3s linear;
}
```

The only concern I have with this is the lack of browser compatibility for IE 8-10 and older Webkit browsers. I've added some browser hacks as per [this page](https://css-tricks.com/using-flexbox/)
, but it still won't work right for old IEs.

Answer (score 1):

I think this is not easy to achieve with pure css. But with a little jquery, its simple. Please try the below sample.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                var columnCount = $(".column").length;
                var columnWidth = $('.column').outerWidth();
                var colWrapperWidth = (columnCount * columnWidth)+'px';
                $(".col-wrapper").css("width", colWrapperWidth);
            });
```

```css
.content{
                height: 50px;
                width: 500px;
                float: left;
                border: solid 5px red;
                overflow-x: scroll;
                overflow-y: hidden;
            }
            .col-wrapper{
                float: left;
            }
            .column{
                width: 100px;
                border: solid 2px white;
                float: left;
                background: green;
                color: white;
                text-align: center;
                line-height: 20px;
            }
```

```html
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
            <div class="col-wrapper">
                <div class="column">column01</div>
                <div class="column">column02</div>
                <div class="column">column03</div>
                <div class="column">column04</div>
                <div class="column">column05</div>
                <div class="column">column06</div>
                <div class="column">column07</div>
                <div class="column">column08</div>
                <div class="column">column09</div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Sorry, I want to use CSS only.

Answer (score 0):

Change you css to following will work nice. Use `display:flex;` and remove `position:absolute` from `section` and `board-container`

```
div#board-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  display:flex;
}

section#kanban-board {
  display:flex;
}
```

**[Updated Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jpj2cuo7/9/)**

Comment: This one is almost there, except now the columns don't scroll vertically when they are larger than the height of page. All the columns do line up correctly horizontally though.

Comment: Almost there. But still can't scroll down the column. The scrollbar is there, but doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, still the same issue. The columns should be 100% high and scroll, but they are less than 100% and don't scroll.

Answer (score 0):

css replacement

```
div#board-container {
  /* overflow: hidden; remove this */
}

section#kanban-board {
  display:flex;
  margin-bottom: 49px;
}

div.kanban-individual {
  flex:0 0 320px;
  vertical-align: top;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #e3e3e3;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  -moz-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  -o-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  -ms-transition: background 0.3s linear;
  transition: background 0.3s linear;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jpj2cuo7/7/

new link

https://jsfiddle.net/jpj2cuo7/12/

Comment: This doesn't show all the columns still. Can't see the last column with heading 'This list is hidden'

Comment: Thanks @RhysStephens I lost that plot, answer edited.

Comment: I can see all the columns now, but none of the columns have vertical scrollbars. They need to scroll individually when the content overflows.

Answer (score 0):

Use This

```
section#kanban-board{ display: inline-flex;}
```